# Mixing dynamic and static linking with gcc

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, autotools

ALL,

I know static linking is frown upon in *nix world, but...

I made a static library that exports a class and will be used by other (dynamic) libraries.

So, as an example I have foo.a, bar.so and baz.so.

bar.so use the class from foo.a and functions from baz.so. baz.so is not written by me and so does not use anything from those 2 libraries. foo.a exported class is not using anything from bar or Baz libraries.

Generally speaking, foo.a is an interface which contains a class with a bunch of pure virtual functions that are implemented inside bar.so

So, now my question is - how do I properly link them?

TIA!!

EDIT:

I tried basic -L/path/to/library -lfoo -L/path/to/library -lbar, but am getting ld error during the run-time that class from foo is not there.

Comment: Neither a static nor a dynamic library can export a class.  They can provide functions belonging to a class and even instances of a class, but the class itself has no representation that can be stored in a library.  That's what headers are for.

Comment: Do you mean you get an error from `ld` when you build a program that uses libbar?  Because that's not what I would call "run-time", but it is the time when `ld` runs.  You won't get `ld` errors at runtime.

Comment: The linker command line is order sensitive, especially when static libraries are involved.  Is your issue resolved if you use `-lbar -lfoo` instead of `-lfoo -lbar`?  The former is the correct relative order if libbar uses functions from libfoo.

Comment: @JohnBollinger,, to answer your first question - no building is successful. I can even successfully run `make install`. But then when I try to run the program it fails because the ld couldn't find the class from the .a library...

Comment: I'm sorry, but no, you are misunderstanding something.  Probably several things.  The *ELF interpreter* (probably ld_linux.so.2 for you) might fail to find things at runtime, but that's an altogether different thing from the linker, `ld`.  And again, nothing is looking for classes at runtime, because they don't exist as coherent entities in that context.  The interpreter will be looking for the class's *methods*, but not for the class itself.

Comment: The issue is probably that you have to do your choice of one of two things: (i) when you build `libbar`, use the appropriate option to make it bundle in the contents of libfoo, OR (ii) include libfoo in the link (after libbar) whenever you build a program that uses libbar.